# Error message in Integration

Tags: rest-api, integration

***Error Message REST Method***

How to create error message for this REST API code,

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/api/Contact/*')
global with sharing class ChildRelatedRecords
{
    @HttpGet
    global static Contact doGet() 
    {
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
     String AccountId = req.requestURI.substring(req.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
      Contact result = [SELECT Id, Name,Account.Name FROM Contact WHERE Id=: AccountId];    
    return result;
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why do you want to generate an exception in your code.

Looking at your code, here are the ways you can generate an exception

- By passing invalid `ID` i.e. by passing any string in the `URL` as parameter which will give you `invalid ID field: yourstring`
- By passing valid 18 or 15 digit `ID` in the `URL` as parameter which does not exist or which is of any other type other than `Contact` which will not retrieve any records and will give you `List has no rows for assignment to SObject` as you are not using `List`

Ideally you should handle all these above scenarios in your code.

**Note :** The variable name that you have used to filter records is `AccountId` and you are filtering by `ContactId` i.e. `Id`

Comment: Hi @user73898 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.